# WaitForMultipleObjects() access denied

Tags: c++, winapi, synchronization, kernel

I have this below thread function, that simply wait on two kernel objects to be signaled.
The waiting function always return **`WAIT_FAILED`** with **`error code 5 (access denied)`** and I can't tell why.

```
unsigned __stdcall func(void * p_this){
    ReceiverThread * ThisObj = (ReceiverThread *)p_this;
    HANDLE ClientsMutex = ClientsInterface::GetClientsMutex();
    HANDLE WaitFor[2];
    WaitFor[0] = ThisObj->PassiveEvent;
    WaitFor[1] = ClientsMutex;
    res = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, WaitFor, TRUE, INFINITE);
    switch (res)
    {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0: // both signal
        if(!Clients->empty()){
           dosomthing();
           ReleaseMutex(ClientsMutex);
           ResetEvent(WaitFor[0]);
        }
        break;
    case WAIT_ABANDONED_0:
        MessageBox(NULL, "WAIT_ABANDONED", "WAIT ERR", MB_OK);
        break;
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        MessageBox(NULL, "TimeOut !", "WAIT ERR", MB_OK);
        break;
    case WAIT_FAILED:
        MessageBox(NULL, "Function Failure !", to_string(GetLastError()).c_str() , MB_OK);
        break;
    }
}
```

The event initialization is as follow:

```
PassiveEvent = CreateEvent(
    NULL,              
    TRUE, // ResetEvent is required to set the event to non-signal state.   
    FALSE, // non-signaled initial state.             
    NULL
);
```

The mutex initialization is as follow:

```
Mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
```

I know it's little opaque, but that's all the information, maybe I'm missing something that is clear, but I can't tell why the `WaitForMultipleObjects()` get **`access denied`**. any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't use OpenEvent? In this case you have to specify SYNCHRONIZE...

Comment: positive, only CreateEvent @xMRi

Comment: I'm running it as an administrator @A.Godnov

Comment: I'm doing so, take a look at the first case in the switch ... @A.Godnov

Comment: I mean that you have to `ResetEvent` before call `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

Comment: I'd suggest creating all your mutexes and events using their `ALL_ACCESS` flags (`MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS' and 'EVENT_ALL_ACCESS'). That will rule out any permissioning issue.

Comment: the initial state of the event is non-signaled. So I believe it's not neccessery. An other thread sets the event to signaled when triggered. the call for waitformultipleobjects is triggered before the setevent for sure ... @A.Godnov

Comment: *I'm running it as an administrator* - this is absolute unrelated. are you sure that you got correct handles in `WaitFor` ? dump handles value after create and before call `WaitForMultipleObjects`

Comment: The handle returned by `CreateEvent` has the `EVENT_ALL_ACCESS` and the handle returned by `CreateMutex` has the `MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS`. I think you have to use `SetEvent` to set the state of an event object to signaled.

Comment: @A.Godnov - all this unrelated to error access denied

Comment: @RbMm I did this, they all show a valid memory address.

Comment: i mean not memory address but handle values. are it the same, when you create this handles. if yes - look for handles types and access. here possible only 2 variants - or you use wrong handles, or close original (and recreate another objects with the same handle value)

Comment: I understand, the handle values are unique and valid, these were the first things I've checked @RbMm

Comment: in this case check it access mask and type.

Comment: @A.Godnov: If you decide to submit another edit request, make sure to follow the rules. Don't put tags into question titles, and don't put *"Q"* into a question title. No need to add any of that redundancy.

Comment: [mcve] required.

Comment: @RbMm "The handles returned by CreateEvent, CreateMutex, CreateSemaphore, and CreateWaitableTimer have full access to the new object." MSDN.. sorry for the delay, I was not around.

Comment: this and prove that you use another handle. may be registry key handle for example